# ¿Qué consume menos recursos de CPU en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero saber qué forma es más optima a la hora de programar en python de cara a que requiere menos recursos de computación.

1. Opción

```py
if move.route_ids and 'with' in move.route_ids.mapped('order_point'):
  move.order_point = 'with'
else:
  move.order_point = 'without'
```

2. Opción

```py
 move.order_point = 'without' 

 if move.route_ids and 'with' in move.route_ids.mapped('order_point'): 

    move.order_point = 'with
```

Comment: Entiendo que la primera es más legible pero el else aporta mucha más lógica ?

Comment: Ambas ejecutan una comparación. La primera siempre realiza una asignación; la segunda puede realizar dos.

Comment: @CandidMoe entonces la asignación consumiría mas recursos que un else?

Comment: @alejandroascasc En python no existen _asignaciones_ tal como se entiende en programación imperativa de una región de memoria donde guardas un valor. Todas las cadenas de texto "existen" en memoria, lo que llamamos "variables" son tan solo referencias a esas cadenas. En lo que se gasta CPU es en las comparaciones. Aparte de esto, python 3.11 introduce un optimizador de ejecución tan bueno que hace innecesario preocuparse tanto por estas cuestiones.

Comment: Sé más claro. ¿Por consumir menos recursos te refieres a que el uso del procesador sea menor o que utilice menos memoria?

Comment: Muy buena aportación, no tenía ni idea de esto @ChemaCortes gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de responder es usando un *perfilador* como `cProfile`, que viene con Python.

El perfilador ejecuta el código e informa el tiempo consumido en cada función y el número de llamadas.

El patrón usual es colocar cada cosa a probar en una función diferente:

```
def cond1(move):
    if move.route_ids:
        move.order_point = 'with'
    else:
        move.order_point = 'without'


def cond2(move):
    move.order_point = 'without'

    if move.route_ids:
        move.order_point = 'with'
```

Tenemos entonces dos funciones, `cond1` y `cond2`, que reciben un objeto de algún tipo, lo evalúan y según eso cambian un atributo del mismo objeto. Siendo la misma evaluación para ambos, puedo simplificar la expresión para facilitar la prueba sin alterar el resultado.

También *maqueteo* una clase para pasar como argumento a las funciones:

```
class Move:
    def __init__(self):
        self.route_ids = None
        self.order_point = None
```

Ahora voy a probar llamando repetidamente a una y otra función, pasando el mismo objeto.

```
iteraciones = 1_000_000

def test():
    move = Move()
    for i in range(iteraciones):
        move.route_ids = random.randint(1,10) > 5
        cond1(move)
        cond2(move)
```

Finalmente, invoco al perfilador pasando en una cadena la expresión Python que debe ejecutar:

```
cProfile.run('test()')
```

El resultado es:

```
         7598933 function calls in 2.916 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.916    2.916 <string>:1(<module>)
  1000000    0.621    0.000    1.375    0.000 random.py:200(randrange)
  1000000    0.332    0.000    1.707    0.000 random.py:244(randint)
  1000000    0.538    0.000    0.754    0.000 random.py:250(_randbelow_with_getrandbits)
  1000000    0.182    0.000    0.182    0.000 scratch_8.py:24(cond1)
  1000000    0.198    0.000    0.198    0.000 scratch_8.py:31(cond2)
        1    0.828    0.828    2.916    2.916 scratch_8.py:38(test)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scratch_8.py:7(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.916    2.916 {built-in method builtins.exec}
  1000000    0.077    0.000    0.077    0.000 {method 'bit_length' of 'int' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1598928    0.140    0.000    0.140    0.000 {method 'getrandbits' of '_random.Random' objects}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hay que fijarse en estas líneas

```
  1000000    0.182    0.000    0.182    0.000 scratch_8.py:24(cond1)
  1000000    0.198    0.000    0.198    0.000 scratch_8.py:31(cond2)
```

que nos dicen que la alternativa 1 (if-else) demoró 0.182 segundos en resolver 1 millón de pasadas. La alternativa 2 (asignar-if) demoró un poco más, con 0.198 segundos para el mismo número de pasadas.

Los datos confirman la estimación de que la alternativa 2 terminará ejecutando más asignaciones que lo necesario, y por tanto será más lenta.

En el peor de los casos, la alternativa 2 hará el doble de asignaciones que la alternativa 1.

Answer (score 0):

Va a depender mucho del contexto. Supongamos que a estas líneas:

```
move.order_point = 'with' 
move.order_point = 'without'
```

Las contásemos como un ciclo de CPU, en el primer caso

```
if move.route_ids and 'with' in move.route_ids.mapped('order_point'):
  move.order_point = 'with'
else:
  move.order_point = 'without
```

Dependiendo la condición siempre usaríamos 1 ciclo de CPU.

Para el segundo:

```
move.order_point = 'without' 

if move.route_ids and 'with' in move.route_ids.mapped('order_point'): 

   move.order_point = 'with
```

Si se cumple la condición, usaríamos 2 ciclos de CPU. Si no se cumple, sólo 1. O sea, esta opcion a pesar de ser más legible en muchos casos, tiene un costo computacional que depende de lo siguiente.

### ¿Qué hago dentro del if?

Ahora reemplazemos las asignaciones

```
move.order_point = 'with' 
move.order_point = 'without'
```

Por

```
move.order_point = requests.get(ENDPOINT_API1)
move.order_point = requests.get(ENDPOINT_API2)
```

O peor aún

```
move.order_point = brazo_robotico.moverA(punto1)
move.order_point = brazo_robotico.moverA(punto2)
```

Está claro que, en el caso de una llamada a un endpoint, con la opción 2 cuando se cumpla la condición vamos a tener un programa más lento. Y en el caso de, por ejemplo, un movimiento robótico, tendríamos sin dudas un comportamiento indeseado, pues el brazo estaría haciendo movimientos innecesarios para quién lo está observando.

En resumen, depende del contexto, y qué tan pesadas sean esas líneas. La legibilidad a veces tiene un coste.

Comment: Estoy super agradecido por tu respuesta! Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo a la hora de contestar.